# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph in a EUSFLAT2019_template.tex

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs, intersections

I have downloaded on my local machine eusflat 2019 template for paper
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/eusflat-2019-template/jmqvcrhkqhgx
and using it in miktex following section in EUSFLAT2019_template.tex

```
\section{How Microsoft detects anomaly in azure}
Microsoft uses a technology called security center \cite{microsf41} in its cloud environments.To detect threats and reduce false positives Security Center
 collects data from Azure resources and network and then applies a lot of  machine learning and big data algorithms to detect threat.These techniques as more advance than normal signature based anomaly detection techniques.It is impossible to 
manually identify the attack and predict the attack when it might happen.So the Microsoft \\ Security Centre uses following technologies
    \newline
```

shows output in log as

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

so I want to know why is this giving me message for badness in the template.

Comment: Do not use `\newline`.

Comment: that message means that you have misused `\\ ` (or `\newline` in this case) . But again why are you making everything more complicated by using a complicated example template designed for a conference that was last year????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am learning things and by doing mistakes I learn more. I have already prepared one 35 page report in latex on overleaf last year but that time I did not had time to do experiement with , or learn properly. I am using template just to reduce my work so that if I have to send a paper to next conference I am fully aware of latex and its uses. Also I like to learn things this way.

Comment: @koeradoera it really makes no sense to start from a big under documented template that has lots of code that you do not need and makes things work differently from documented behaviour. You should start from a simple document that just has `article` class and no packages and just add packages _if you need them_.

Comment: ok I will keep this suggestion in mind , I have lot more documents to write.This one document which I have now prepared it nearing to finish once I finish this I will try what you said.